# Does '#' has special meaning in Mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

```
describe('#indexOf()'....
it('#doSth()');
```

Does '#' has special meaning in Mocha? What does `describe` and `it` actually do? sorry not found document for `describe` and `it`

Comment: Take also a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25092025/57091).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`describe` and `it` follows a pattern called `BDD`, which means "Behaviour Driven Development". It just defines an interface that makes you think a little different about how you write your tests, at least it should. Nesting of `describe` also makes it possible to group your tests functionally, and the resulting report has a "readable" feeling to it.

Quoting the example from the [Mocha docs](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#getting-started):

```
describe('Array', function(){
    describe('#indexOf()', function(){
        it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function(){
            assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(5));
            assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(0));
        })
    })
})
```

It reads:

> Array#indexOf() should return -1 when the value is not present

The first two describes just sets up the (descriptional/grouping) scope, and the `it` is the actual test that is run. `#` has no special meaning. In this case, it just makes the output text/report look a little more API-doc like.

Answer (score 8):

The '#' has no special meaning. It is a common standard to prefix # to a method for a certain class. e.g. `Array#indexOf()`.

I had exactly the same questions on `describe()` and `it()`, which the documentation didn't explain much.

Hence I wrote a [blog post on a guide to mocha](https://samwize.com/2014/02/07/a-guide-to-mochas-describe-it-and-setup-hooks/). In short:

- `describe()` is merely for grouping, which you can nest as deep. Also known as a test suite.
- `it()` is a test case

Comment: link is expired. please update with new one or remove the expired link.