# What is the role of describe() in Mocha?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

The documentation at [the official Mocha site](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) contains this example:

```
describe('User', function(){
  describe('#save()', function(){
    it('should save without error', function(done){
      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.save(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        done();
      });
    })
  })
})
```

I want to know when I should nest my tests in the `describe` function and what the basic purpose of `describe` is. Can I compare the first argument passed to `describe` to comments in a programming language? Nothing is shown of `describe` in the output on the console. Is it only for readability purposes, or there is some other use for this function?

Is there anything wrong if I use it like this?

```
describe('User', function(){
    describe('#save()', function(){
        var user = new User('Luna');
        user.save(function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
            done();
        })
    })
})
```

If I do it this way, the test still passes.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206894/does-has-special-meaning-in-mocha

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The `it` call identifies each individual tests but by itself `it` does not tell Mocha anything about how your test suite is *structured*. How you use the `describe` call is what gives structure to your test suite. Here are some of the things that using `describe` to structure your test suite does for you. Here's an example of a test suite, simplified for the purpose of discussion:

```
function Foo() {
}

describe("Foo", function () {
    var foo;
    beforeEach(function () {
        foo = new Foo();
    });
    describe("#clone", function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            // Some other hook
        });
        it("clones the object", function () {
        });
    });
    describe("#equals", function () {
        it("returns true when the object passed is the same", function () {
        });
        it("returns false, when...", function () {
        });
    });
    afterEach(function () {
        // Destroy the foo that was created.
        // foo.destroy();
    });
});

function Bar() {
}

describe("Bar", function () {
    describe("#clone", function () {
        it("clones the object", function () {
        });
    });
});
```

Imagine that `Foo` and `Bar` are full-fledged classes. `Foo` has `clone` and `equals` methods. `Bar` has `clone`. The structure I have above is one possible way to structure tests for these classes.

(The `#` notation is used by some systems (like for instance, jsdoc) to indicate an instance field. So when used with a method name, it indicates a method called on an instance of the class (rather than a class method, which is called on the class itself). The test suite would run just as well without the presence of `#`.)

#### Provide Banners

Some of Mocha's reporters show the names you give to `describe` in the reports they produce. For instance, the `spec` reporter (which you can use by running `$ mocha -R spec`), would report:

```
  Foo
    #clone
      ✓ clones the object 
    #equals
      ✓ returns true when the object passed is the same 
      ✓ returns false, when... 

  Bar
    #clone
      ✓ clones the object 


  4 passing (4ms)
```

#### Help Select Parts to Run

If you want to run only some of the tests, you can use the `--grep` option. So if you care only about the `Bar` class, you can do `$ mocha -R spec --grep Bar`, and get the output:

```
  Bar
    #clone
      ✓ clones the object 


  1 passing (4ms)
```

Or if you care only about the `clone` methods of all classes, then `$ mocha -R spec --grep '\bclone\b'` and get the output:

```
  Foo
    #clone
      ✓ clones the object 

  Bar
    #clone
      ✓ clones the object 


  2 passing (5ms)
```

The value given to `--grep` is interpreted as a regex so when I pass `\bclone\b` I'm asking only for the word `clone`, and not things like `clones` or `cloned`.

#### Provide Hooks

In the example above the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` calls are hooks. Each hook affects the `it` calls that are inside the `describe` call which is the parent of the hook. The various hooks are:

- `beforeEach` which runs before each individual `it` inside the `describe` call.
- `afterEach` which runs after each individual `it` inside the `describe` call.
- `before` which runs once before any of the individual `it` inside the `describe` call is run.
- `after` which runs once after all the individual `it` inside the `describe` call are run.

These hooks can be used to acquire resources or create data structures needed for the tests and then release resources or destroy these structures (if needed) after the tests are done.

The snippet you show at the end of your question won't generate an error but it does not actually contain any test, because tests are defined by `it`.

Comment: Hi, just for theory purposes, can you have a `describe` in an `it`? I would never do that, but if I did, would it break the tests?

Comment: A `describe` in an `it` is meaningless as far as Mocha is concerned. So the behavior you'd get is undefined. I've just tried it: `it` containing `describe` containing `it`. Mocha executed both tests. However, this is not a behavior you can rely on. Because Mocha does not attribute meaning to `describe` in `it`, the next version of Mocha could behave differently with the test case I had, and this would be fine because I'm doing something outside Mocha's contract so Mocha is not bound to act in the way I'm assuming it should.

Comment: Keep in mind that the hooks have a strict execution order. Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/harto/c97d2fc9d0bfaf20706eb2acbf48c908) or the [docs](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) to understand it.

Answer (score 10):

It's hard to add to Louis' excellent answer. There are a couple of advantages of the describe block that he didn't mention which are the `skip` and `only` functions.

```
describe.skip(...) {
...
}
```

will skip this describe and all its nested describe and it functions while:

```
describe.only(...) {
...
}
```

will only execute that describe and its nested describe and it functions. The `skip()` and `only()` modifiers can also be applied to the it() functions.

Comment: Just to add, these settings take effect in the entire test suite. So if you have 10 different test files, and you use ``describe.only()`` in one of those, then the 9 other test files are also skipped.

Comment: And if you use ``describe.only()`` in two different places, both will run.

Answer (score 8):

To my knowledge, describe is really just there for humans... So we can see different areas of the app. You can nest describe n levels deep.

```
describe('user',function(){
    describe('create',function(){}
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Describe is just used for the sake of understanding the purpose of the tests , it is also used to logically group the tests . Lets say you are testing the database API's , all the database tests could come under the outer describe , so the outer describe logically groups all the database related . Lets say there are 10 database related API's to test , each of the inner describe functions defines what those tests are ....

Comment: Why did they not call it a suite and follow normal unit testing terminology?

Comment: @AndrewS you can also use the word "suite" and "describe" can be used interchangeably. You can also call "it" and "test" https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/mocha.js#L249-L263

Answer (score 0):

The particular role of describe is to indicate which component is being tested and which method of that component is also being tested.

for example, lets say we have a User Prototype

```
var User = function() {
    const self = this;

    function setName(name) {
        self.name = name
    }

    function getName(name) {
        return self.name;
    }


    return{setName, getName};
}

module.exports = User;
```

And it needs to be tested, so a spec file is created for unit test

```
var assert = require('assert');
var User = require("../controllers/user.controller");

describe("User", function() {
    describe('setName', function() {
        it("should set the name on user", function() {
            const pedro = new User();

            name = "Pedro"
            pedro.setName(name);
            assert(pedro.getName(), name);
        });
    });
});
```

It is easy to see that the purpose of describe is indicating the component to be tested and the nested describe methods indicate which methods needs to be tested