# Can `describe` contain a mix of `describe` and `it` in Mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have this simple example unit test in Mocha:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver')
const chai = require('chai')

chai.should()

var customer
var gigger
var admin

/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */

/* globals describe,it */

describe('start all tests', async function () {
  describe('create customer user', async function () {
    it('creates a user browser', async function () {
      customer = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build()
      customer.should.not.be.null

      this.timeout(5000)

      await customer.get('http://www.google.com/ncr')
      await customer.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN)
      await customer.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000)
    })
    it('creates a gigger browser', async function () {
      gigger = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build()
      gigger.should.not.be.null
    })

    it('creates an admin browser', async function () {
      admin = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build()
      admin.should.not.be.null
    })
  })

  describe('close it all down', async function () {
    it('close all browsers down', async function () {
      await customer.quit()
      await gigger.quit()
      await admin.quit()
    })
  })
})
```

Everything works fine. BUT! If I un-comment the last `describe`:

```
//describe('close it all down', async function () {
  it('close all browsers down', async function () {
    await customer.quit()
    await gigger.quit()
    await admin.quit()
  })
//})
```

What actually happens is that `close all browsers down` actually runs *straight away*.

Is that because `describe` functions *must* contain either all `describe`  functions, rather than `it` as well? If so, this is not documented.

Or, am I missing something?

**ADDENDUM**: In fact, how does Mocha *actually* work? I got so used to just typing it, that I never quite got into the actual workings of it. What does Mocha's `describe()` actually do? Does it just run the callback? When another nested `describe()` is called, how does it figure out that it's a nested one, and which one the parent is? How does it all work, "in general"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all your tests are running asynchronously so you cant control the execution flow of them, for what you want to do, you should use an after() see mocha [hooks](https://mochajs.org/#hooks)

For your other question you should see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298118/what-is-the-role-of-describe-in-mocha) where its really well explained. Happy Testing !

Comment: I added another question... please let me know if you are able to answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `describe` can contain a mix of `describe` and `it` in Mocha. And also, the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` defined in outer `describe` will apply to test cases in nested `describe` as well.

Run below example:

```js
describe('test suite', () => {

  before(() => {
    console.log('    >>> outer before all');
  });

  after(() => {
    console.log('    <<< outer after all');
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('      >>> outer before each');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    console.log('      <<< outer after each');
  });

  describe('# nested test suite', () => {
    before(() => {
      console.log('      >>> # nested before all');
    });

    after(() => {
      console.log('      <<< # nested after all');
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
      console.log('      >>> # nested before each');
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      console.log('      <<< # nested after each');
    });

    it('nested test', () => { })

  })

  it('test', () => { })
});
```

From the output you can see the order of the hooks:

```
  test suite
    >>> outer before all                 \
      >>> outer before each     \         |
    ✓ test                       |        |
      <<< outer after each      /         |
    # nested test suite               \   |
      >>> # nested before all          |  |
      >>> outer before each        \   |  |
      >>> # nested before each  \   |  |  |
      ✓ nested test              |  |  |  |
      <<< # nested after each   /   |  |  |
      <<< outer after each         /   |  |
      <<< # nested after all          /   |
    <<< outer after all                  /
```