# What is describe() in Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js

I am trying to get my hands dirty with Mocha and here is the example I saw from documentation:

```
var assert = require("assert")
describe('Array', function(){
  describe('#indexOf()', function(){
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function(){
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(5));
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(0));
    })
  })
})
```

Most of the examples show the second describe statement

```
  describe('#indexOf()', function(){
```

starting with `#` in `#indexOf()`. What is the significance of this `#`? Why can this not be written simply as `indexOf`? Where can I get a fundamental understanding of how the describe works?

PS: I looked at the documentation at http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#interfaces but can't figure out how these came into picture and how are these interfaces processed.

Thx

Comment: That's jus a string, it means absolutely nothing. It's just like Array#indexOf(), basically indexOf is a function of the Array Class/Object

Comment: why do all people give answers without minimal research?, `#` does means something (instance method), and it's well established convention, I added my answer below.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298118/what-is-the-role-of-describe-in-mocha#_=_

The answer there answers this as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the bdd syntax of mocha is a inspired in ruby's [RSpec](http://rspec.info/), therefore you'd find the best tips for mocha's conventions searching for RSpec, here's a good place to start:

http://betterspecs.org/

In particular the `#` is mentioned there:

> For instance, use the Ruby documentation convention of . (or ::) when referring to a class method's name and # when referring to an instance method's name.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code of Mocha, I don't see it doing anything significant with a `#` appearing in the first parameter of `describe`.

This being said, in some documentation systems for JavaScript (for instance, [jsdoc](http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html)), the use of a `#` indicates that what follows belongs to an object instance, rather than to the object's class. So `Foo#bar` would be something you could call like this:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar(...);
```

Not like this:

```
Foo.bar(...)
```

The latter would be represented as `Foo.bar`. So it would make sense in a test suite to use the same kind of notation to distinguish whether the methods being tested belong to instances or classes.

Answer (score -1):

> starting with # in #indexOf(). What is the significance of this #?

None. Some people think that it looks better.

> Where can I get a fundamental understanding of how the describe works?

It's basically a way to group your tests together and run `before`/`after` for a group of tests.

You'll know when you need it, and if you're asking this question, you can safely ignore all `describe`'s and write tests without them.