# What is the name of the unit test naming convention that is prefixed with "#" and "." in the test names?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I've seen some tests written this way and I would like to know if anyone knows what is the name of this convention:

```
describe("users/domains/services/user-service", () => {
  describe("UserService", () => {
    describe(".create()", () => {
      ...
    });

   describe(".update()", () => {
      ...
   });
    
    // Static method
    describe("#new()", () => {
      ...
    });
  });
});
```

If someone can help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: Maybe related [Referring to javascript instance methods with a pound/hash sign](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587896/691711)

Answer (score 2):

This way of referring to a method or variable comes from [jsdoc](https://jsdoc.app/) and is called a [namepath](https://jsdoc.app/about-namepaths.html). For example, `MyClass#myMethod` could be used in a doc comment to refer the method named `#myMethod` in the class named `MyClass`.

The use of this convention for JavaScript tests is very prominent in the [mocha.js documentation](https://mochajs.org/). An equivalent style has also [been proposed](https://www.betterspecs.org/#describe) by [betterspecs.org](https://www.betterspecs.org/) as a best practice in Ruby, and there's [some discussion about it](https://github.com/betterspecs/betterspecs/issues/2) there. I don't know who first adopted the style, and I don't think it has a name.

There's some more relevant answers in [this related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353562/what-is-describe-in-mocha).